# How can I get a list of files and maintain their directory structure in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have a directory `c:\mydir` that has many files and directories.  I'd like to get a specific list of files and sub-directories (the entire sub-directory, recursive) so I can then perform an operation to copy just those files to c:\mydir2

```
$stuff = ???        .\foo.ini, 
                    .\bar.exe, 
                    .\README.TXT,
                    .\dir1, 
                    .\dir2
```

So this mystery operation would return 3 files, and 2 complete sub-directories.

Then how can I pass $stuff into `Copy-Item` to copy those files into C:\mydir2?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation and examples for [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) .. the Include/Exclude or Filter params will help you with this task.

Comment: I see 3 approaches depend on what you need to do: 1. as @James C. said 2. use .NET "Directory" class 3. use external application (can be more faster than others)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question completely. Next oneliner should copy all files in the structure below C:\MyDir to C:\Mydir2. Just the files, no folders. Name conflicts could be your next problem.

```
(gci C:\MyDir -Recurse -File).fullname |%{Copy-Item $_ c:\MyDir2}
```